# After adding, removing and adding again annotations in MapBox iOS SDK, can't click on the annotations

Tags: swift, swift2, annotations, mapbox

I am using :

```
func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView?
```

to add annotations but somtimes the user can't click the annotations

Comment: please supply more code and explain exactly what you mean.

Comment: Hi I cannot remove annotations, can you provide your way?

Answer (score 0):

After a long time i tried to solve this question, i figured that every MGLAnnotationView i am adding need to be forced with ".enable = true"
and it works :)